# OL3 ImageStatic and rotation?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm developing a tool to rotate a static image layer and currently facing an issue rotating around the center.
Static image layer must be rotated around a specific point.
I use precompose and postcompose hooks to alter canvas and make the rotation.
But image is rotated around left bottom corner, not center:

```js
imgLayer.on("precompose", evt => {
  const ratio = ol.has.DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO
  const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(center)
  const ctx = evt.context
  ctx.save()
  ctx.translate(pixel[0] * ratio, pixel[1] * ratio)
  ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180)
  ctx.translate(-pixel[0] * ratio, -pixel[1] * ratio)
})
imgLayer.on("postcompose", evt => {
  const ctx = evt.context
  ctx.restore()
})
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wkkwbw85/

How to rotate relative to the center?

Comment: If you know the size of image, you can translate the image center like,
`ctx.translate(pixel[0] * ratio-100, pixel[1] * ratio+100)
  ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180)
  ctx.translate(-pixel[0] * ratio-100, -pixel[1] * ratio+100)`

Comment: I'm know the size of the original image, but on each zoom the image size changes... https://jsfiddle.net/wkkwbw85/2/ - this is bad